# bug or wrong way for VALUES in SPARQL, OpenLink Virtuoso?

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I have Virtuoso 7.10 and command  VALUES works for 1*x or x*1 asign to tables like:

```
SELECT * WHERE 
{
VALUES (?z ?r ?t)
{
 ("x" "y" "z")
}
}
```

and for:

```
SELECT * WHERE 
{
VALUES ?z
{
 "x" "y" "z"
}
}
```

But the problem is when i try to assign like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE 
{
VALUES (?z ?r ?t)
{
 ("x" "y" "z")
 ("xy" "yx" "zx")
}
}
```

then in result, i have only first column filled, but other two are empty (same as with two column).
Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Try asking on a Virtuoso mailing list.  Stackoverflow isn't really the place to discuss (potential) bugs in particular systems.

Comment: For what it's worth, DBpedia is running Virtuoso 07.10.3211, and `select * where { values (?a ?b ?c) { ("a" "b" "c") ("d" "e" "f") } }` returns the expected results (two rows will all columns filled).  Since this doesn't seem to be *easily* reproducible, it's probably a better fit for the Virtuoso mailing list.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming issues (C, Java, etc.).  Software issues are better raised elsewhere.  OpenLink Software (my employer) provides several paths for Virtuoso support including [public Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/), [public Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users), [private Support Cases](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).